# ¿Conectar a otro servidor al fallar el principal?

Tags: linux, servidor, hosting, vps

tengo una consulta en cuanto a hosting y servidores linux. 
Supongamos que tengo la web www.miweb.com, que tiene los DNS 123.123.123

Hay alguna forma de que cuando el servidor este offline por algun inconveniente tecnico, automaticamente se redireccione a otro servidor auxiliar, asi tendriamos dos servidores y nunca estaria fuera de linea.

Luego cuando el servidor principal este online nuevamente, usamos este.

¿Si la web es dinamica, y se va guardando info en base de datos y demas, como puedo mantener ambos servidores actualizados?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

En la mayoría de los casos se utiliza un archivo .htaccess o un script PHP para redireccionar un dominio. La ventaja de estos métodos reside en que es posible definir individualmente qué código de estado HTTP debe mostrarse al agente de usuario, caracterizando así las redirecciones como temporales o permanentes. Así, resultan relevantes especialmente dos códigos de estado HTTP, el 301 y el 302:

```
301 – Moved Permanently: la página solicitada por el agente de usuario estará disponible de manera permanente bajo la URL redireccionada. La antigua URL será, por lo tanto, inválida. 

302 – Moved Temporarily: la página solicitada por el agente de usuario está temporalmente disponible bajo la nueva URL. A diferencia de la redirección 301, la antigua dirección sigue siendo válida.
```

En caso de que no se defina específicamente el código de estado HTTP, el servidor mostrará por defecto un código de estado 302, lo que no siempre es ideal. Por lo tanto, es aconsejable introducir manualmente todos los códigos de estado para evitar errores de indexación como el URL Hijacking. A diferencia de la redirección 301, el código de estado 302 le comunica al crawler que la URL original debe seguir siendo indexada. De mantenerse activa, la URL antigua competirá con la nueva en el índice de los motores de búsqueda.

Fijate si a traves de un error puedes redireccionarla a otro hosting con .htacess

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responder.
Creo que no es lo que estoy buscando.
Yo necesito que cuando un servidor se caiga, automaticamente se conecte o se redireccione a un servidor auxiliar.

Habia escuchado que se podia hacer "Crossfire" o algo asi, no recuerdo bien el termino.